# Reusable modal window directive. How can I pass directive-attributes-values to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-controller

I want to make a reusable modal-window-directive (i found a pair modal-window examples, but that's not what i want, or they do not work properly).

It should look something like this:

**(1)**  title-, body-text and function-name (for the function, which is binded to the action-button in the template) are defined directly within directive

```
<my-modal 
    modal-title="Modal Window Title" 
    modal-body="This is my Modal Window Body"  
    click-main-html-action-button="myControllerActionFunction()">
</my-modal>
```

**(2)** The HTML-template for modal window must pick up the corresponding values

```
 <div class="panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         {{title}} 
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">**{{body}}**</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="templatestartaction(); $event.stopPropagation()">Start action</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**(3)**  Button-function for modal window must be defined In the controller

```
app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
    scope.title = "";
    scope.body = "";
    $scope.myControllerActionFunction = function () {
        console.log('myControllerActionFunction', title);
    };
})
```

> The question is:  how can I read the attrs values from **(1)**
>   (modal-title = "Modal Window Title", etc.) and the function name
>   (click-main-html-button action = "myControllerActionFunction ()") and
>   pass it to the model and function definition in the controller
>   **(3)**, so that it is displayed in the html-template **(2)**?

I can  read the attributes from **(1)**, but I do not know how i pass it in controller.

**(4)**

```
app.directive('myModal', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        //template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    templateUrl: "directives/modal/view/modalWindowTemplate.html"
        scope: {
        templatestartaction: '&clickMainHtmlActionButton'
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.title = attrs.modalTitle;
            scope.body  = attrs.modalBody;                 
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define title and body in the controller like

```
$scope.modalProps = {
    title: 'My modal title',
    body: 'My modal body'
};
```

Use this in the html

```
<my-modal 
   modal-title="modalProps.title" 
   modal-body="modalProps.body"  
   click-main-html-action-button="myControllerActionFunction()">
</my-modal>
```

And define it for the directive

```
app.directive('myModal', function () {
return {
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    //template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    templateUrl: "directives/modal/view/modalWindowTemplate.html"
    scope: {
        templatestartaction: '&clickMainHtmlActionButton'
        title: '=modalTitle',
        body: '=modalBody'
    },
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I found already similar example, but I need the directive in the exact same form as in my example (1). The question is: is it possible?  If not, then I use this solution.

Comment: Well, you could add another function like templatestartaction but for setting title and body of the controller from within the directive. That way the markup of the directive template for title and body doesn't change.
Or you can use require in the directive. That way you can inject the (parent) controller into the directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive => "Creating Directives that Communicate")